# Should posters be allowed to remove comments from other users on their posts?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I end up having shortish discussions about one of my questions in its comments. One example of this was today, on [What is the preprocessor macro to test whether an application extension is being built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018380/what-is-the-preprocessor-macro-to-test-whether-an-application-extension-is-being#comment37021555_24018380).

In this case, the user cleared something up for me. Now that the discussion is over, I'd like to be able to remove these comments. I feel that the comments will have no benefit to future readers, and are really just in the way. I can remove my own comments, but I cannot remove any other user's comments.

One solution would be to publicly reply to the user stating "okay, I think this discussion is done, why don't you delete your comments and I'll delete mine", but since there is no notification of deleted comments on your post, there is no guarantee that we would both delete our comments at near the same time. There *must* be an easier way!

I think it would be nice to be able to remove other users comments on my posts, possibly only in certain conditions, such as only after 2 days.

What do you think?

Comment: And what's wrong with flagging the comment as "Obsolete"?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't know that this would be appropriate. How are comments judged to be obsolete?

Comment: That's what the flag is there for.  The basic interpretation is "this comment was useful but is no longer relevant".  The other option is to not delete anything and just flag the **question**, select other, and tell the moderator that the comment conversation is no longer relavant and you would like them to clean up the comments.  From the question, they can clean them up in 1 swoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag the comment as obsolete. If a moderator notices, it will be removed. (This is more likely to happen if you remove all your comments first.) You can also flag the entire question saying that all the comments are obsolete. Or you can comment saying "I'm going to delete all my comments now that they're obsolete, and you should too." Of course you then have to decide how long to leave that one there before deleting it, so it's suboptimal.

You might also be interested in [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/147247) and my answer to it, along with many of the linked questions to it.

Comment: You're right, this is suboptimal. I removed mine and flagged the others, and now all I can do is wait :-).